# Regex in java for recognizing specific text in file

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to use split function to cut the text below in a way that only the `title` and the `booktitle` sections are returned. For example a sample text is like this

```
@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/crowncom/Chatzikokolakis15,
  author    = {Konstantinos Chatzikokolakis and
               Alexandros Kaloxylos and
               Panagiotis Spapis and
               Nancy Alonistioti and
               Chan Zhou and
               Josef Eichinger and
               {\"{O}}mer Bulakci},
  title     = {On the Way to Massive Access in 5G: Challenges and Solutions for Massive
               Machine Communications - (Invited Paper)},
  booktitle = {Cognitive Radio Oriented Wireless Networks - 10th International Conference,
               {CROWNCOM} 2015, Doha, Qatar, April 21-23, 2015, Revised Selected
               Papers},
  pages     = {708--717},
  year      = {2015},
  crossref  = {DBLP:conf/crowncom/2015},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-24540-9_58},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-319-24540-9_58},
  timestamp = {Wed, 14 Oct 2015 08:42:42 +0200},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/crowncom/Chatzikokolakis15},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}
```

and I want as an exit these 2 blocks as separate strings:

```
booktitle = {Cognitive Radio Oriented Wireless Networks - 10th International Conference,
               {CROWNCOM} 2015, Doha, Qatar, April 21-23, 2015, Revised Selected
               Papers}


title     = {On the Way to Massive Access in 5G: Challenges and Solutions for Massive
               Machine Communications - (Invited Paper)}
```

Can anyone please help me with the regular expression that applies in Java and especially in the split method?

Comment: "especially in the split method" why do you want to use `split`? It would require from you to describe everything you don't want. Maybe focus on things you would like to find instead and use `Pattern`/`Matcher` combination.

Comment: Anyway is format used here fixed or can it change? Can we use fact that *sections* describing attributes starts with exactly two spaces?

Comment: It looks like you need to be able to accept braces nested to any depth within the matched sections, like  {{{{}}}}...   that actually can't be done quite properly with a regular expression

Comment: @MattTimmermans true, but if we won't try to do everything in one regex and ignore for now `{` and `}` we can focus on number of spaces at start of each line to separating each sections. Rest is simply checking first word in section (`title` or `booktitle`). But since I really don't like to correct problems which could be avoided by having more informations about format used in text I will wait until OP confirmations that we can actually rely on number of spaces.

Comment: Besides what everyone said, what have you tried to solve your problem? Or are waiting to us just do it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Java regex can find your two subtexts:

```
(?s)(?<=[\r\n]+  )(?:title|booktitle) += \\{.*?\\}(?=,[\r\n]+  \\w|[\r\n]+\\})
```

You can then use `startsWith()` to find which subtext is which.

*Test*

```
String input = "@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/crowncom/Chatzikokolakis15,\r\n" +
               "  author    = {Konstantinos Chatzikokolakis and\r\n" +
               "               Alexandros Kaloxylos and\r\n" +
               "               Panagiotis Spapis and\r\n" +
               "               Nancy Alonistioti and\r\n" +
               "               Chan Zhou and\r\n" +
               "               Josef Eichinger and\r\n" +
               "               {\"{O}}mer Bulakci},\r\n" +
               "  title     = {On the Way to Massive Access in 5G: Challenges and Solutions for Massive\r\n" +
               "               Machine Communications - (Invited Paper)},\r\n" +
               "  booktitle = {Cognitive Radio Oriented Wireless Networks - 10th International Conference,\r\n" +
               "               {CROWNCOM} 2015, Doha, Qatar, April 21-23, 2015, Revised Selected\r\n" +
               "               Papers},\r\n" +
               "  pages     = {708--717},\r\n" +
               "  year      = {2015},\r\n" +
               "  crossref  = {DBLP:conf/crowncom/2015},\r\n" +
               "  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-24540-9_58},\r\n" +
               "  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-319-24540-9_58},\r\n" +
               "  timestamp = {Wed, 14 Oct 2015 08:42:42 +0200},\r\n" +
               "  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/crowncom/Chatzikokolakis15},\r\n" +
               "  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}\r\n" +
               "}\r\n";
String regex = "(?s)(?<=[\r\n]+  )(?:title|booktitle) += \\{.*?\\}(?=,[\r\n]+  \\w|[\r\n]+\\})";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

*Output*

```
title     = {On the Way to Massive Access in 5G: Challenges and Solutions for Massive
               Machine Communications - (Invited Paper)}
booktitle = {Cognitive Radio Oriented Wireless Networks - 10th International Conference,
               {CROWNCOM} 2015, Doha, Qatar, April 21-23, 2015, Revised Selected
               Papers}
```

Comment: What puzzles me is how Pattern is able to compile `(?<=[\r\n]+  )` without complains about lack of obvious maximum length in look-behind... This won't work for instance with `(?<=_f+)` but works fine for `(?<=f+)` or `(?<=f+_)`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that helps you.

```
String bibtex  = "<your giant string>";

for ( String s : bibtex.split("}\\s*,") )
{
    if ( s.trim().startsWith("booktitle") ||  s.trim().startsWith("title") )
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: While it can work in this case I would avoid relying on splitting on `},` since we can't be sure that it won't be any nested inside of data we want to read like `{foo{bar},baz},` in which case we would split after `bar` and `baz`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that format of text is exactly same as you posted you could:

1. remove first and last line
2. split it on two spaces which are placed at start of line and have no space after them (you will need `^` and multiline flag to let it represent start of line, and to test part after thing on which you want to split but not including it in delimiter take a look at [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism).
3. iterate over all sections you obtained from previous split and print ones which start with `title` or `booktitle`